# Why is my code not fetching lists from sharepoint site?

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have been trying to fetch lists from sharepoint site using this code but the list isn't getting loaded into the response. Can someone please help with this?
Also i have tried other solutions too just list fetching is left in this otherwise the code is working fine.
I have mentioned the name of the table correctly and also the URL of the site in serve.json

```
import { IPropertyPaneConfiguration } from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';

import { BaseAdaptiveCardExtension } from '@microsoft/sp-adaptive-card-extension-base';

import { CardView } from './cardView/CardView';

import { QuickView } from './quickView/QuickView';

import { HelloWorldPropertyPane } from './HelloWorldPropertyPane';

import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';



export interface IHelloWorldAdaptiveCardExtensionProps {

  title: string;

  description: string;

  iconproperty: string;

  targetlist: string;

}



export interface IHelloWorldAdaptiveCardExtensionState {

  description: string;

  items:IListItem[];

}

export interface IListItem{

  EmployeeName:string;

  City:string;

  ContactNumber:string;

  BaseLocation:string;

}



const CARD_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID: string = 'HelloWorld_CARD_VIEW';

export const QUICK_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID: string = 'HelloWorld_QUICK_VIEW';



export default class HelloWorldAdaptiveCardExtension extends BaseAdaptiveCardExtension<

  IHelloWorldAdaptiveCardExtensionProps,

  IHelloWorldAdaptiveCardExtensionState

> {

  private _deferredPropertyPane: HelloWorldPropertyPane | undefined;



  public onInit(): Promise<void> {

    this.state = {

      description:this.properties.description,

      items:[]

    };



    this.cardNavigator.register(CARD_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID, () => new CardView());

    this.quickViewNavigator.register(QUICK_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID, () => new QuickView());



    setTimeout(this.loadSpoData,500);

    return Promise.resolve();

  }



  public get title():string{

    return this.properties.title;

  }



  private loadSpoData=async(): Promise<void>=>{

    if(this.properties.targetlist){

      this.context.spHttpClient.get(

        `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/lists/GetByTitle('MyCompanyEmployeeList')/items`,

        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)

        .then((response:SPHttpClientResponse)=>{

          response.json().then((responseJSON:any)=>{

            const items:IListItem[]=(<any[]>(responseJSON.value))

            .map<IListItem>((v:{EmployeeName:string;City:string;ContactNumber:string;BaseLocation:string;}): IListItem=>{

              return{

                EmployeeName:v.EmployeeName,

                City: v.City,

                ContactNumber: v.ContactNumber,

                BaseLocation: v.BaseLocation

              };

            });



            this.setState({

              items:items

            });

          });

        });

    }

  }



  protected loadPropertyPaneResources(): Promise<void> {

    return import(

      /* webpackChunkName: 'HelloWorld-property-pane'*/

      './HelloWorldPropertyPane'

    )

      .then(

        (component) => {

          this._deferredPropertyPane = new component.HelloWorldPropertyPane();

        }

      );

  }



  protected renderCard(): string | undefined {

    return CARD_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID;

  }



  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {

    return this._deferredPropertyPane?.getPropertyPaneConfiguration();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1. Can you verify that the "targetList" property is populated in manifest.json?
2. Can you try removing if(this.properties.targetlist){ (and corresponding closing bracket) and see if the list data will be loaded afterwards. I am not sure what is the purpose of that if check, when you already have title of the list hardcoded later in GetByTitle('MyCompanyEmployeeList')

Comment: Thanks for the help i had to add table id to manifest file and then it worked fine.